# What part of speech is up in the sentence, the time is up

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs

This sentence, the time is up, is confusing me. I think up is a preposition

Comment: Yes, it's a preposition functioning as a subjective complement.

Comment: @BillJ: is 'subjective complement' a fancy name for an 'adjective'? I thought 'up' was an adjective in 'the time is up'

Comment: No:. Subjective complements are typically adjective or noun phrases, but they can also be preposition phrases.

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question strictly so I’m commenting. In terms of language acquisition, I’d accept the entire phrase *to be up* as an idiom and move on, personally. These words put together have a joint meaning simply because we’ve given them that meaning, not because they express anything that can be seen or heard or felt, and replacing “up” with any word of the same part of speech will unpredictably alter the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, "up" is a predicate adjective, with a meaning equivalent to "expired":

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=up)
up (adjective)
10. Having been finished; over: *Your time is up.*

Comment: Most dictionaries classify "up" in this sense as an adverb, but modern grammar takes it as a prep.

Comment: I looked it up(!) in M-W as well, and they show "Time is up" under adjective. But they show "use up" and "get up" as adverbs.

Comment: My MW gives it as an adverb. And so does my Cambridge.

Comment: Interesting. The online Cambridge shows the meaning "ended" as adjective,adverb without further clarification: "up adjective, adverb [not gradable] (ENDED)
finished, or to an end, finish, or state of being completed:
Finish up your breakfast – it’s almost time for school.
My time is almost up on the parking meter."   I guess the reason it seems like an adjective to me is that it describes a state, at least in the uses with "is". The use with "finish" seems adverbial.